# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, exception

What did this excepion means actually??

I've created a new jsp in an existing project in NetBeans 7.0.1 and i am using JDK7.
On running that jsp it  gives the exception which i am unable to understand..

The same is listed here on NetBeans [bugzilla](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201414). but it has no solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201414

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=202250

Comment: I find that difficult to believe--what do you think you changed?

Comment: I've changed the java platform to JDK7..and one thing is when i am trying to run a file via complete project run than it runs successfully but single file did not run or compiled.

Comment: @Asif The solution was to change to 5 or 6, no? Like it says in the bug report? In any case, it's a bug--until it's fixed, you'll need to work around it as suggested, or find another way, or see if there's been a more-recent release that fixes it.

Comment: Yes @Dave i've reverted to jdk6 and all is working fine here..no problem at all. And to use jdk7 i had to wait until bug fix by either netBeans community or by Java.